# Useless MySQL SELECT condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Is the following query:

```
SELECT ... AND (​(({$sql_field}) LIKE '%%') OR ({$sql_field} IS NULL))
```

equivalent to SELECT?

That is, is there any result that would get filtered out by the condition

```
​(({$sql_field}) LIKE '%%') OR ({$sql_field} IS NULL)
```

Comment: can you please clarify more ?

Comment: your opening parenthesis and closing parenthesis count doesn't match!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the parenthesis were balanced at the end, I agree, it seems to be useless.

Looks like some voodoo code to me, I'd be looking in the revision control log to ask whoever wrote it WTF they were thinking :)

Comment: The query is probably dynamically generated and contains some user input between the two percent signs. If the user doesn't enter anything, the dynamically generated query is the above one.

Comment: @JBNizet yeah, that would make sense

Comment: The position I'm in is replaced every year and only by inexperienced people (like myself), whoever wrote this may well be in a different country by now.
I don't think the query is not dynamically generated, it's in a file with utility functions that include a lot of hard-coded table names and such.